# Java URL not working/loading

Tags: java

I'm trying to load a URL but it isn't working, here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        URL url = new URL("google.com");
        String x = url.openConnection().getContent();
        System.out.println(x);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

can any one help me with this?

Comment: describe it isn't working

Comment: The stack trace will tell you **exactly** what's wrong. What don't you understand?

Comment: You should more accurately describe what isn't working. This seems like very basic stuff.

Comment: `URL` includes the protocol being used, also. Without it, it is not a `URL`(in many cases)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java requires you to input the full URL or in other words, basically it requires the protocol as well in this case, I am assuming `http`, so try this:

instead of `google.com` put `http://www.google.com`

This should work.

Answer (score -1):

you can call your executable files. for example`try{
            java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create("ur url"));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}`

or you can create a runtime object. for example`try{
            Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
            r.exec("ur exe file path");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }`